# Facebook API Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I am trying to maken an app with some FB functionalities. I want to use some code from their examples, but I got stuck on the following:

First I create a string format, like so:

```
let userIDKeyFormat: String = "UserID%li"
```

I want to use this userIDKeyFormat to get a value from user defaults:

```
func getUserIDInSlot(slot: Int) -> String? {
    self.validateSlotNumber(slot)

    var key = String(format: userIDKeyFormat, slot)
    var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    return defaults.objectForKey(key)
}
```

Xcode gives me an error on the return line, stating "AnyObject is not identical to String".

Could anyone help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaults.objectForKey(key)` can be a `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, or `nil`

You have to explicitly cast it:

```
func getUserIDInSlot(slot: Int) -> String? {

    ...

    return defaults.objectForKey(key) as? String
}
```

With this, the function returns the `String` value only if `defaults.objectForKey(key)` is a `NSString`, otherwise `nil`.

Comment: Thanks @rintaro That worked! I am still trying to fully understand the optionals subject.